# Do Dementors Have Magic?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, dementors

Are Dementors magical creatures with inherent magical powers?

Or do their powers of despair, depression, cold, and hopelessness come from their eternally soulless existence?

Do we ever see Dementors perform any kind of magic¹ in *Harry Potter*? **Do Dementors have magic?**

¹<sub>Other than the Dementor's Kiss, which I don't know whether or not is magic or pure, unadulterated evil.</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if these qualifies as magical abilities, or if there is a non-magical explanation for these traits, but they all seem magical:

- The are invisible to Muggles
- They fly (without wings)
- They affect emotions of those around them.
- They physically affect the environment around them simply by their presence/proximity

  - Freeze objects (movies)
  - Create fog (result of breeding in the books)
- They cannot be killed/destroyed per a J.K.R. interview available at http://www.mugglenet.com/jkr/interviews/dh-webchat.shtml

> Cornersoul: So what happens to all the dementors where will they go
>   will they be destroyed if so, how J.K. Rowling: You cannot destroy
>   Dementors, though you can limit their numbers if you eradicate the
>   conditions in which they multiply, ie, despair and degradation.

I think that *some* of those traits could be attributed to their soulless nature, but not all.  The invisibility to Muggles, and flight seem to be independent/unrelated to their evil nature.